# Exchange Server 2013 Database Mounting Error

Tags: exchange-server-2013

I got error message in exchange server **Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxOfflineException.** 
So I try to watch my Exchange server database status and it's show me Active and Dismounted.
I am trying to mount the database, but mount command not executed
I got  the error message. How to solve it?

Failed to mount database "Mailbox Database 0389974439". Error: An Active Manager operation failed. Error: The database action failed. Error: Operation failed with message: MapiExceptionDatabaseError: Unable to mount database. (hr=0x80004005, ec=1108) Diagnostic context: Lid: 65256 Lid: 10722 StoreEc: 0x454 Lid: 1494 ---- Remote Context Beg ---- Lid: 45120 dwParam: 0x2649A2 Lid: 57728 dwParam: 0x264A8D Lid: 46144 dwParam: 0x2650B7 Lid: 34880 dwParam: 0x2650B7 Lid: 34760 StoreEc: 0xFFFFFC06 Lid: 41344 Guid: b1f22c9b-393c-41a5-bc7c-0fc65a5dd783 Lid: 35200 dwParam: 0x3D40 Lid: 46144 dwParam: 0x265654 Lid: 34880 dwParam: 0x265654 Lid: 54472 StoreEc: 0x1388 Lid: 42184 StoreEc: 0x454 Lid: 1750 ---- Remote Context End ---- Lid: 1047 StoreEc: 0x454 [Database: Mailbox Database 0389964565, Server: xxxx.mydomain.com]

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28312828/exchange-2013-cannot-mount-database.html) is the source of the answer, but I'll copy it here just in case...

1st check with eseutil /mh  if database is not in clean shutdown, if not just run with /p switch to get it in clean shutdown

Once it come to clean shutdown state, then
 Try moving the checkpoint and logs to a temporary location and mount database to see whether it works.

Get-MailboxServer  | select MaximumActiveDatabases

If the value shows as 0, then you need to change that:

Get-MailboxServer  | Set-MailboxServer -MaximumActiveDatabases 1

The other thing you can do is try restarting the Microsoft Exchange Information Store process. The error (hex) above shows a DB lock, but that could be either the bug from RTM (if you are unpatched) OR something else locking it. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Try moving the checkpoint and logs to a temporary location and mount database to see whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are five possible reasons of "unable to mount database (hr=0x80004005, ec=1108)" error:

1. Missing log files Exchange
2. “Dirty Shutdown” Error
3. Corrupt Exchange Database Files
4. Information Store unable to start
5. Not enough free disk space on database

Please refer following article to resolve "unable to mount database (hr=0x80004005, ec=1108)" error: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-resolve-unable-mount-database-hr0x80004005-ec1108-shelly-bhardwaj